# Set field name when using @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) annotation in Spring MongoDB Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I have an entity and I am using Access set to PROPERTY in one of my getters:

```
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
public MyObj[] getMyObjs() {

   ***Some logic***
}
```

I need to change property name for the stored field so I tried annotating the method with:

```
@Field("my_objs")
```

But it keeps storing field as "myObjs". I can't figure out why this isn't working, any ideas?

Comment: Below code works for me. Can you post your entity class and repository class if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks you mix **SpringData-JPA** with **SpringData-Mongo**.

For **Mongo**,

- Keep the annotation `@Field("my_objs")`
- Remove the annotation `@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)` from
  method

Your sample code should look as follows if you use **Spring Boot 2.3.2.RELEASE**

```
@Field("my_objs")
public MyObj[] getMyObjs() {
   ***Some logic***
}
public void setMyObjs(MyObj[] objs) { 
   ***Some logic***
}
```

Comment: AccessType Annotation is used to define how Spring Data shall access values of persistent properties, and Field is for mapping, so they have different purposes. In SpringData-Mongo @AccessType can be used.